# How to connect postgreSQL DB with ASP .NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, database-connection, npgsql

I have a problem with connection to database in my `.NET ASP` application. Maybe has something wrong with `App.config` or `Web.config`.

It was connected to `MSSQL` by default but I have tried connect it to `PostgreSQL` by `npgsql nuget` package and entity framework.

It don't even see `Database Server for PostgreSQL` when I want to create Migration in my project in `Visual Studio` ( Enable-Migrations; Add-Migration Initial; Update-database).

Here are github links of my code:

[webconfig](https://github.com/Kulawy/BoroWinnicaStore/blob/master/BoroWinnicaStore.WebUI/Web.config)

[App.config](https://github.com/Kulawy/BoroWinnicaStore/blob/master/BoroWinnicaStore.DataAccess.SQL/App.config)

I want to know how make it right and make it work proprely.

Comment: Have you made the configurations necessary to make it work? I don't see in your code any of the methods described in the npsql documentation: https://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html

Comment: That was one of missing parts but i also hadn't done some things which I found when I started searching stuff from your link. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

```
      using System;
   using Npgsql;         // Npgsql .NET Data Provider for PostgreSQL

   class Sample
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        // Specify connection options and open an connection
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;" + 
                                "Password=pwd;Database=postgres;");
        conn.Open();

        // Define a query
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select city from cities", conn);

        // Execute a query
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read all rows and output the first column in each row
        while (dr.Read())
          Console.Write("{0}\n", dr[0]);

       // Close connection
       conn.Close();
     }
   }
```